# Finding object in List without using foreach

Tags: c#, .net

I have list of following class Student

```
class student
{
   Guid id;
   string name;
}
```

The list contains multiple students. To search a student with specific id, I need to use foreach loop and compare id of each student.

I am looking for a better alternative instead of foreach loop. Is there any alternative available?

**[EDIT]:** What I meant by better alternative is optimized solution in terms of execution time and performance

**[EDIT2]** One more twist, what if id is Guid.

Thanks,

Ram

Comment: `Dictionary<Guid, Student>` if it's a Guid.

Comment: As @Saeb mentions, it does not matter a great deal whether the id is a `Guid` or an `int`. Just declare the dictionary accordingly.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Nothing will really change the fact that you have to iterate over the list. But you can use LINQ:

```
List<Student> studentsList = ReadStudentsList();
var student = studentsList.Where(s => s.id == ID_IM_LOOKING_FOR).Single();
```

Based on an answer by @Fredrik Mörk, this could be shortened to:

```
var student = studentsList.Single(s => s.id == ID_IM_LOOKING_FOR);
```

Also note, that [`Single()`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb535118.aspx) will throw an exception, if no student is found. If you'd prefer to just return `null`, use [`SingleOrDefault()`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb342451.aspx).

But what you *actually* want to be doing is storing your students in a map:

```
Dictionary<int, Student> students = ReadStudentsMap();
var student = students[ID_IM_LOOKING_FOR];
```

This has a *way* better performance (O(1) for hashtables, O(log(n)) for trees) than looking through the list (O(n))!

Answer (score 6):

If each `student` can appear in the list only once, you might want to use a `Dictionary<int, stutent>` instead. Then you will have a very efficient way of looking up students by id.

```
Dictionary<int, student> students = GetSomeStudents();

// locate student with id = 42
if (students.ContainsKey(42))
{
    var student = students[42];
    // do something useful
}
```

Comment: +1.  He could also have used `List<>.Contains` but it's worth noting that'll just be a reference comparison unless `student` implements `IComparable<>`.

Comment: The student is not a type though? It's a string. So `Dictionary<int, string>` is the more likely choice surely?

Comment: @SkonJeet, based on the OP's question, student is a class so it's a Type, a reference type.

Comment: @Moo-Juice, `List<T>.Contains` is much slower because it enumerates the collection to find a match. In fact, in Big-O notation, search time for `List<T>.Contains` is `O(n)` while for `Dictionary<K,V>.ContainsKey` it is `O(1)`.

Comment: @Saeb - yes but the student class is comprised of an int and a string. If you're to include this int as the key to the dictionary then all that's left for the value is the string?

Comment: @Saeb, I agree completely.  The OP was initially using a List<> however.  I upvoted this answer and suspect its the best solution, but I commented for completeness :)

Comment: @SkonJeet, the `Student` _objects_ are the values, while their unique `id` is the key used in the dictionary. i.e. when you search the dictionary based on an ID, you get a reference to the student object with that unique ID.

Comment: @SkonJeet Yes, following the OP, `student` is a class, containing the properties `id` and `name`. The dictionary will use the `id` as Key, and the full `student` object as Value.

Answer (score 2):

You can use LINQ:

```
var student = students.SingleOrDefault(s => s.id == 12);
```

[Enumerable.SingleOrDefault Method](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb342451.aspx)

Answer (score 1):

LINQ is option if you dont want to go for foreach lop so you code will be as below

```
var student = studentsList.FirstOrDefault(s => s.id == ID_IM_LOOKING_FOR);
```

Answer (score 0):

Here's an idea, to avoid having to iterate over the list :

- Sort the list by Student.Id
- Implement a more sophisticated search algorithm (e.g. Binary Search [binary search](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Binary_search_algorithm))

Answer (score 0):

You can use any collection that uses hash lookup because their member look up is very quick. e.g. `Dictionary <K,V>`, `OrderedDictionary`. There is also the nongeneric `Hashtable` which is mostly rendered redundant by the generic `Dictionary<K,V>`. In Big-O notation, element retrieval time by key for these collections is `O(1)`, which is as good as it gets.

For accessing elements, to not incur the cost of two lookups, instead of using `ContainsKey`, you can use the `TryGetValue` method, e.g.:

```
Dictionary<Guid, Student> students = GetStudents();

Student student;
if (students.TryGetValue(guid, out student))
{
    // found
}
```

BTW, `OrderedDictionary` also allows you to access elements by index.